# Why did France just give up without a major fight in WW2?

Tags: 20th-century, world-war-two, france

Why did France give up when Paris was taken in WW2? They could have kept fighting just like the Polish did.

Comment: The French did not give up "When Paris was taken". They did keep fighting. The "Cheese-eating surrender-monkeys" is a joke from The Simpsons that has no bearing to reality. As a percentage of the population, more French died fighting than Americans.

Comment: I have reworded the question. Perhaps it can be reopened in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu: That's not a rewording of the question - it is an entirely new question on a vaguely contemporary topic.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: My version of the question is "different" in the sense of being more objectively worded.  It also has several reopen votes. I'll leave it up to the OP (Young) as to whether he would rather have it reopened in its current form, or closed in its original form. If he prefers, he can roll it back.

Comment: I'd say that at it's core, the question is the same just social bias has been removed from the question.

Comment: It's definitely a better question. However, now the answer is incorrect. I think it should be posted as a new question instead and leave it up to the OP if he want's to post it. :-) I rolled it back.

Comment: I don't see why there are down-votes, though perhaps not a politically correct, it is a valid question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Up to you. The gist of the original version of the question was "Why didn't the French continue fighting?" (a broad question that elicits subjective answers). I changed the thrust to why "couldn't" the French continue fighting?, which can be answered objectively. Note also that there have been votes to close after the rollback. And the one answer does answer my "revised" version, why "couldn't" the French keep fighting.

Comment: @TomAu: No, the gist was "Why didn't they fight", which is incorrect. It should be closed. If there had been no answers already, that would have been a different issue.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I'm OK with the answer for either version of the question, the OP's or mine.

Comment: I see that the question is wrong factually. However, should we be closing factually incorrect questions instead of answering why they are factually incorrect?

Comment: @Russell Although it is a valid question (which is why I chose to leave it open), it shows a lack of research effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without a major fight! Where do you get your facts?

Loss of over 1.5 million prisoners in less than 6 weeks, loss of virtually 100% of fighters and modern tanks, plus 100% of the artillery, firearms and ammunition stored in the Maginot Line left France completely defenceless. Sixty one of 117 total divisions had surrendered, the BEF had evacuated twice, leaving French units vastly outnumbered and out-gunned by the Germans.

France surrendered on June 16, 37 days after the invasion on May 10; the last Polish regular army units surrendered on October 2, 32 days after invasion on September 1.  I don't see that there is a major difference here.

Comment: The French had plenty of aircraft left, unfortunately it was in the south.  The French in general did not lose close to 100% of anything, but one would appreciate a source if you're so inclined to speak in near absolutes.

Comment: Yes, no doubt quite true; but how many were first-line fighters capable of making an ME-109 pilot break a sweat?. The French also had more operational tanks on June 16 than the Germans did; but they were 3-man tanks designed as WWI-style mobile artillery platforms, couldn't fire and steer at the same time, and were all dispersed as infantry support. The French Army and Air Force were operationally prostrate, and France had lost the industrial capacity to maintain a continuing supply system.

Comment: It is important to give sources for all these claims.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens answering a false claim with your own false claim isn't going to give you credibility. The French did not lose even close to 100% of their equipment, though you may be right that they lost close to that in combat capable equipment. Of course they also didn't "hold out for 4 years" as the original claim says, keep to your debunking that and you've an answer here.

Comment: @jwenting: An injured or sick soldier is a casualty until he returns to duty with a combat unit. Similarly an inoperational tank or plane is a casualty until it is both operational and assigned to a combat unit capable of using it. Realistically, the French army itself had ceased to exist as a viable fighting force by June 17, with 2/3 (1.5MM of 2.2MM) of the force assigned to defend Northern France having surrendered, and a further 200,000 killed, wounded or missing. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_France)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens no need to educate me on the definitions, thank you very much. Your claim that 100% of their material was destroyed though is laughable, as a lot of it was never in combat, being out of position in what became Vichy or in the colonies (there was for example a major French military presence in Algeria and Morocco, which never saw combat before the fall of France, later joining either the German Afrikakorps or the allied forces (or being destroyed by the Royal Navy).